# Add a custom attribute to Ember.$.ajax response

Tags: ajax, ember.js, response

I would like to do some complex parsing of my API response for errors and return the errors in the response. I would like to overwrite the response from Ember.$.ajax to add some information.

`Ember.$.ajax(...).then(function (response) {
  response.errors // custom errors attribute
});`

EDIT: the point of this question, is NOT to do it in the callback. I don't want to parse the response on every single callback of the application.

If you have another suggestion to do the same, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Do anything what you want with your response inside callback. Or write some more to describe your problem.

Comment: The point is not to do it in the callback. This wouldn't be DRY.

Comment: For ember-data I used http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload

Comment: Yes but it won't be called for Ember.$.ajax right?

Comment: The only solution I can think of at the moment is to wrap Ember.$.ajax, and chain a then to it. I'd love something cleaner though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69488/discussion-between-karellm-and-alex-tonkonozhenko).

Comment: How about use $.ajaxSetup and specifiy the datafilter property?